# Refreshing a UITableView When A Segue Happens to Another View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a strange situation here with what I believe will be an easy fix, but I just can't find what that is.

I have a `UITableViewController` with a `UISearchBar` at the top. The `UITableView` gets populated by the user clicking on a `NavigationBarButton` (Add Entry) and filling in some information into the `UITextFields` which gets saved to `Core Data`. The `UITableView` is using `NSFetchedResultsController`.

In the `searchBar`, the user can search for Names. The searching itself works really well because if the name doesn't exist, the user is presented with a `UILabel` saying "No results found". This label is created in the `viewDidLoad` of this `UITableView` and displayed in the `searchBar's` `textDidChange` method:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    self.timelineSearchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    _fetchedResultsController = nil;
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        // Handle Error
    }
    else
    {
        [self.timelineTableView reloadData];
        [self.noResultsLabel setHidden:_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count > 0];
        if (![self.timelineSearchBar isFirstResponder])
        {
            self.shouldBeginEditing = NO;
            [self.timelineTableView reloadData];
            [self.timelineSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
        }

    }
}
```

**The Problem**

The problem comes from a particular set of steps.

1) Search for an entry that doesn't exist

2) No results label will be displayed

3) Without cancelling the search, Add an Entry (which segues to the new view controller)

4) When the "save" button is clicked on the new view controller, it dismisses that view and brings the user back to the UITableView.

5) The no results label is still visible as is the search string in the searchBar.

The same result occurs even if you search for a particular user and find a matching result and then add an entry before cancelling the search; when you return to the UITableView, the search is still displayed.

I've tried a combination of a few things.

In the `viewWillAppear`, I put `[self.tableView reloadData]`; but that didn't make a difference.

I'm thinking I have to do something in the `prepareForSegue`, so if it segues to the Add Entry or with the user clicking on a cell (two different segues), it should:

1) Cancel the existing search

2) remove the noresultsLabel if there

3) Display the TableView with no search results

How would I go about achieving this?

Any guidance would really be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you should reload the table in the completion handler of the new view controller's dismissal.  Alternatively, the Add Entry button should cancel the search and reset the table before the segue happens.

Comment: Thanks @nhgrif - that's very helpful. I was thinking about the second approach but I wasn't sure how to achieve that. Should I essentially, set the searchBar text to nil, and reloadData for the TableView in the prepareForSegue?

Also, do I need to call the textDidChange, or any other method?

Comment: I just tried that, with the setting the SearchBar text to @"" and reloading the data, and while it removes the text from the searchBar, it doesn't "cancel the search" with reloadData.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue in perhaps a crude way; disabling the Add Entry button while the search is up and running. I don't believe this is the best way to achieve this but the user would have to cancel the search to add an entry. I'll continue to find a better way to achieve this.